# How to change my WPF treeview to use property columns

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to create a "copy" of such an application: [Example of disk analyzer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8Ivs.png)

I managed to create a simple treeview with folders, I can expand them, but my treeview only contains the names of the folders and files [Example of what I managed to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuEBq.png)

My XAML code contains only one additional line of code to the default

```
<TreeView Name="treeView" Margin="5"></TreeView>
```

And my MainWindow.xaml.cs contains code like this (this part is for drives only)

```
public void LoadDirectories()
        {
            var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            foreach (var drive in drives)
            {
                this.treeView.Items.Add(this.GetItem(drive));
            }
        }

        private TreeViewItem GetItem(DriveInfo drive)
        {
            var item = new TreeViewItem
            {
                Header = drive.Name,
                DataContext = drive,
                Tag = drive
            };            
            this.AddDummy(item);
            item.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(item_Expanded);
            return item;
        }
```

How can I create more "properties" for the "item"? For example, I wrote a code to calculate the size of the folder, and I want to show the size near the name of the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## #1 DataTemplates

At first you need to create separate model for storing all necessary properties you want to display. It will look something like:

```
public class ItemModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Size { get; set; }
}
```

While initializing specify the model as the DataContext

```
var item = new TreeViewItem
{
     Header = drive.Name,
     DataContext = new ItemModel
     {
         Name = drive.Name,
         Size = CalculateSize(drive)
     },
     Tag = drive
};
```

Finnally create specific DataTemplate according to your needs right in the XAML.

[More](https://wpf-tutorial.com/treeview-control/treeview-data-binding-multiple-templates/)

## #2 Header

As an alternative approach, you can set the calculated size within the header field:

```
var item = new TreeViewItem
{
     Header = $"{drive.Name} - {CalculateSize(drive)}",
     DataContext = drive,
     Tag = drive
};
```

## #3 Composite

For this approach please consider to use the Composite pattern. We will need to create separate Item and Folder classes. The Folder class itself will contain a list of Items to be displayed. HierarchicalDataTemplate can store and display corresponding items inside of it.

[More](https://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern)